# Where can I find the version info in the dist of the angular2 application?

Tags: angularjs, angular2-services

I have put the version(version: '0.0.0') in the package.json and environment.prod.ts. After the build (ng build --prod) in which file should I get the version information in the dist?

Answer (score 0):

Package versions will not build in production dist. In production dist we can't find any package versions.

Comment: So there is no way to know which application version is deployed on prod??

Comment: As per my understanding there is no way to get versions.